# Server Async Sockets - Detect closed connection from client?

Tags: c#, sockets, connection

I have the following source code from ms site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx

I'm trying to detect when the client has closed connection.

One way I tried was to keep sending data to client until I get exception. I created a new thread which gets executed once at onDataReceive, but I get an error "Cannot access disposed object" on:

```
m_workerSocket[socket_id].Send(bytes);
```

but if I put it in directly in onDataReceive it works fine. Why do I get this exception when trying to access socket from another thread?

Then I found the second solution:

```
static class SocketExtensions
{

    public static bool IsConnected(this Socket socket)
    {
        try
        {
            return !(socket.Poll(1, SelectMode.SelectRead) && socket.Available == 0);
        }
        catch (SocketException) { return false; }
    }
}
```

Which I wanted to run in a separate thread too, to check whenever socket gets closed, but I get the same error. I only get error if I try to do this from a thread, if I place both solutions in one of the functions, they execute fine. Any ideas how to get this running from a thread?

Comment: The only reliable way to detect socket disconnects is by trying to read from the connection, not write to it.

Comment: Thanks! I keep getting the same error, any tips what am I doing wrong!?!

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    String content = String.Empty;

    // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket from the asynchronous state object.
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = state.workSocket;

    if (handler != null && !handler.Poll(1, SelectMode.SelectRead) && handler.Connected && handler.Available == 0)
    {
        // Read data from the client socket. 
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // Parsing data received in here..

            // Enabled received for next data
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (handler.Connected)
        {
            // Client are offline will be detected here
            IPEndPoint clientIP = handler.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("IP Client: {0}:{1} disconnected", clientIP.Address, clientIP.Port));
        }
        {
            // Server are offline will be detected here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In condition

if (handler! = null &&! handler.Poll (1, SelectMode.SelectRead) && handler.Connected && handler.Available == 0)

I would swap the order

if (handler! = null && handler.Connected &&! handler.Poll (1, SelectMode.SelectRead) ...
otherwise, when the socket is not connected, the Poll function ends with an exception.

Answer (score 1):

If only problem is to determine when client is disconnected:
I had the same problem in my socket server, and finally I decided to send disconnect "flag" from any client to server when it's disconnected.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried the disconnect flag, but unfortunately it doesn't work out for me. I simply need to detect when to close the connection.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is handle your unload function correctly for your clients to detect a client side abnormal close. The client.connected is not very reliable on the server side but this should help.

IE...

```
protected override void UnloadContent()
    {

        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here            
        if (client != null)
            client.Close(); // I exist so close the connection...

        // I would place a timout on the server side 
        // client.Available as well to drop inactive clients...

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000); // Force the Client to stay open long enough to communicate a closure...          
    }
```